# HTML Form into CSV Files with JS and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, csv

I found a script on jsfiddle for export an html form into CSV file. 
It's work with checkbox and input, but not with Select. Can you help me please
I get the all the possibility and the result into my csv. I only want the result, ty.

Here is my code:

https://codeshare.io/50qV48

Thank's you

Comment: What? That's not a picture? I know it's a code

Comment: Why not copy the value from select to a hidden input before converting to csv?

Comment: omg, you shouldnt do like this at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have all the results (input, select, textarea...) in one array with jQuery, just use :

```
var data = $('.mySelector').serializeArray();
```

Et voila !

Example:

```
<div class="box"> 
  <input name="lang" value="fr" />
  <select name="liste">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
  </select>
</div>


<script>

var data = $('.box').serializeArray();

// result of data
/* 
  data = [
    { 
      name:"lang"
      value:"fr" 
    },
    { 
      name:"liste"
      value:"2" 
    }
  ];
*/ 
</script>
```

Comment: J'appuye sur le petit valider à  gauche?